# Continuous Query on json url to Elastic

Tags: json, amazon

I need to poll every hour a url and store the (small) data that it returns in json format to Elastic.... Is this something I can/should do from Kibana with a plugin? Or is there some lightweight service that can be run on a dockerfile to poll and push to elastic with relatively small configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would just script it and run it as a cron job. Something simple like

```
curl "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/Amsterdam" | curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/my-index/_doc"
```

should do the job, but maybe you have to add additional parameters if e.g. you use authentication for your Elastic instance.